# Tracking arrival and depatures in remote locations

Tags: mobile-data, gps, remote-access

I am hoping for suggestions of how to track the arrival and departures of health care workers in remote locations. An idea proposed was to use some sort of a GPS tracker. Is this feasible? Any cheap GPS's that you would suggest? Also we are wondering how to more promptly receive the health data that they collect. Currently they take pictures and someone in the office has to fill in the form manually. Is there a better way? Please advise.

Comment: Stack Exchange sites work best when answering a single question, can I suggest you edit the question to only cover the tracking and then look at a second question about anything else (as long as it's covered by the description here https://iot.stackexchange.com/help/). Also we will probably need more information about the situation to be able to help.

Comment: what is `cheap` to you?

Comment: you have left out information .... this is not a good description of a system that you are using `they take pictures and someone in the office has to fill in the form`

Comment: Agreed. Please read [ask] and update - this has the potential to be an excellent question.  Battery life will be a bottle neck, although solar power might help - where is this located? And, do the workers have cheap Android 'phones, or can you afford them? Can you describe the "use case" in more detail? Thanks

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure if this question is best suited here or on https://iot.stackexchange.com/ as it seems to involve designing a system, not just recommending some software. It's a great question, though. With more details, I would like to design a solution